# Despite hosting on nginx works fine in local web, it does not work with external ip

Tags: nginx, hosting

I have configured .net and nginx on ubuntu and it works in local web perfectly. I have static external ip, I have configured port forwarding on my router (I had done it for postgresql and it works fine from external web so I think I have done it properly) When it comes to nginx and when i type my ip f.e: xx.xx.x.xx:80 in url on computer in another web site is unreachable.

I have opened ports in firewall on linux:

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp

sudo ufw enable
```

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Do the logs say anything?

Comment: Now I have tried to install only nginx and make it's default website accesible from external ip. I forwarder port 80 on router and it's the same. There must be something I missed.

Comment: I have nothing in error.log. Access.log has another entry when I type my server ip in local web and see nginx default web but anything besides it

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I find solution but still I don't know why it works this way. I have changed listen port to 9000 or any different instead 80 in nginx config and in my router forwarding. Now everything works fine, why port 80 does not work?